# Git Workflow everything I read is backwards to what I need

Tags: git, workflow

I am struggling with a basic Git concept... where does the repository code originate?

This is primarily because a website is usually already in place when I am asked to start. Everything I read seems to assume the project will originate in a local repository.

Here's what I am doing:

1. Set-up Empty Bit-Bucket Repository
2. Terminal onto Website Server
3. `git config` (name/email)
4. `git init`

Now how do I get all of the website (remote) files onto the BitBucket repository for the first time?

From there, I can make a local clone.

Comment: Bitbucket has [a guide on how to do exactly this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/import-code-from-an-existing-project-259358821.html#Importcodefromanexistingproject-Importanexisting,unversionedcodeprojecttoanemptyrepository). I would just add that the first step would be to identify which files/directories you *don't* want to commit and first commit your `.gitignore` file accordingly.

Comment: I wanted to get everything though the first time. I mean everything, an exact clone.

Answer (score 0):

You need set remote of your local repo then push all files to remote with

```
git remote add origin https://xxxx
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thank you. I did just that and it says EVERYTHING UP TO DATE but no files were sent to Bitbucket ?

Comment: `git init` just creates an empty repository. Setting up the remote is necessary, but then, when you push, you're pushing an empty repo into an empty repo, and that would be "up to date". 

Try adding and committing some content, and then pushing.